# Flash/HTML5 player with HTML controls?

Tags: html, flash, web, video-player

I'm searching for a player that can handle MP4, H263, MP3/MP4A/OGG, WEBM, OGGV and.. FLV. It's supposed to run only on chrome so it supports the html5 format. I tried video.js but it doesn't play FLV. Are there any players (especially free) that can handle all formats? I'd prefer to have to change only a skin of html.

Answer (score 1):

There are many players available for the same but I guess there are some which support all the extensions mentioned..

here are some of them

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28836/media-format-support/

http://www.hdflvplayer.net/blog/html5-support-availed-for-hd-flv-player/

This will help you understand some of the supported formats..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Hope it helps..

Comment: For free ones, I guess you have to use html5 default one and add some codecs to support FLV type. I encountered similar problem once but dont remember the solution. I am checking it on my side. I'll update you when if found...!! :)

Comment: Here are some others, http://mediafront.org/osmplayer/#.UVA0wxf-G84 and http://html5video.org/wiki/Kaltura_HTML5_Player_Options_and_API or http://mediaelementjs.com/ <-- This supports many formats including FLV... Try and let me know if any works for you... :)